# Cause vi's visual mode to go in opposite directions?

Tags: visual-mode

If I enter visual mode I can select lines either up xor down, but not both.  Is there a way to make vim do both?

I'm particularly interested in this for purposes of searching, entering visual mode, searching again, and then searching in the opposite direction so I can extract a piece of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press `o` while in visual mode to switch to the opposite end of a visual selection, thus using it to switch direction of your highlight.